# .NET: Is There an Interface for Implemented by all XML Serialized objects?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I want a method to return an XML Serialized Typed object. Is there an interface I can use to enforce this requirement?

Comment: what does this question even mean? you want a method that will serialize an object??

Comment: Hum.. I'm not sure how else I can rephrase my question for you to understand. HackedByChinese answered my question since you last posted which can hopefully give you a clue what i meant to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) will allow you to customize XML serialization/deserialization. However, it still uses XmlSerializer to serialize data to or from XML.

Answer (score 1):

Implement [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx

Comment: Nope but similar. That's the XML serialization interface, I'm referring to the XML serialization attribute. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no interface that means "this object can be XML Serialized". `IXmlSerializable` means that the caller is stating that it implements XML Serialization on its own, and that the XML Serializer does not need to generate code to serialize it.

The following type is XML Serializable, but does not implement `IXmlSerializable`:

```
public class SerializeMe
{
    public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
}
```

There is no interface that could be used as a return type which could both return an `IXmlSerializable` instance and the above class.